# RestAssured with Junit4 throws ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch

Tags: maven-3, rest-assured

I'm trying to setup a simple rest-assured testcase with Junit 4.8 and maven3 with dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But this throwns me

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 34 more
```

I used doc from https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted
And checked https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/FAQ

Any help very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a dependency to a parent pom which caused the ClassNotFound Exception, after removing the dependency it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding the correct version of httpclient. The version of rest-assured I am using is **2.3.4** so the correct version of httpclient for it is **4.3.5** . With regards to this question, since you are using rest-assured version **1.8.0**, the correct version of httpclient to use is **4.2.1**